# Missing CloudTable.Execute (and all non-async methods) in ASP.Net 5 Projects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-table-storage

Using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 RC, if I create a new "ASP.Net Web Application", and go to NuGet and add a reference to the latest version of Azure Storage (Install-Package WindowsAzure.Storage -Pre), in the CloudTable class, all I see are the *Async methods:

[image: Picture of intellisense with only Async methods]

However, if I create a new Console Application or Class Library (normal class library and console application, not a "Package" one) then I see all the methods as I expect:

[image: Picture of Intellisense with all methods]

And it isn't just intellisense, the methods seem to actually be missing. If I go out to the package in windows explorer I see separate folders for dnx451, dnxcore50, and net40. Only the net40 library contains those methods (using JetBrains dotPeek to look).

Why would these methods be missing in the "dnx" versions of the code?

Answer (score 1):

This library is in preview. The plan is to support synchronous methods but for now you can use Task.Wait for synchronous calls.

Comment: My issue was not understanding that ASP.Net 5 uses some magical version of .Net that is not the full .Net and that there is no real way to configure it to work like it used to.

Comment: I have the same problem in VS 2017 in a ASP.NET Core project, in which I added the WindowsAzure.Storage NuGet

Comment: This is still a problem, using NuGet package WindowsAzure.Storage v8.7.0, in my case in an Azure Functions C# project. For example, there's no `ExecuteQuery()` method, only `ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync()`. The only documentation I can find for `CloudTable` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.cloudtable?view=azure-dotnet doesn't mention anything about different methods on different architectures. What is it that determines the API available?