# How to use WindowsAzure.Storage.Table in .NET Core projects?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-storage

I installed the [Windows Azure Storage 8.1.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage) NuGet package in my newly created ASP.NET Core Web project, in Visual Studio 2017.

Actually I try to use it, like the [Microsoft docmentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables#retrieve-all-entities-in-a-partition) suggests(`table.ExecuteQuery(query)`), but have only the "Async" methods:

[image]

The code:

```
public class HelloWorldController : Controller
{
    public string ReadTables() {
        CloudStorageAccount storage = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connStr.MyTablesConnStr);
        CloudTableClient tableClient = storage.CreateCloudTableClient();
        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("themes");

        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder("Here is your test Table:");
        var query = new TableQuery<ProjectThemeEntity>() {
            SelectColumns = new List<string> {"RowKey", "Description" }
        };

        // No way to do it in the controller action ?! ----------
        var items=await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync<ProjectThemeEntity>(query, null);

        foreach (ProjectThemeEntity item in items) {
            response.AppendLine($"Key: {item.RowKey}; Value: {item.Description}");
        }

        return response.ToString();
    }
```

I found there were similar problems in the past, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30673266/missing-cloudtable-execute-and-all-non-async-methods-in-asp-net-5-projects)...

Any idea how to workaround this?

Comment: You should find out how async functions work (Tasks etc.). Since you are on MVC from the looks of it, the framework itself fully supports asynchronous actions.

Comment: @juunas I would use, if there were some documentation on that usage... I didn't find, even in the Microsoft documentation there is any example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Serge .NET Core doesn't yet include Sync Implementation of the APIs. so you can **use ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync instead**. check [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/367)

The article you're following also doesn't say that it is for .NET Core.

[image]

Comment: where can I find some examples of how to use that methods?

Comment: you can refer to "Retrieve entities in pages asynchronously" in the same documentation you're referring to and also this [one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/vs-storage-aspnet5-getting-started-tables)